# Верстка дизайна сайта

Tags: html, дизайн, вёрстка

Как сделать широкую шапку сайта более `1280px`, при фиксированной ширине сайта, `#wrapper
width: 1000px;`. Проблема в том, что на разрешении 1024х768 появляется горизонтальная прокрутка, подскажите, как с этим справиться??!

Answer (score 1):

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Comment: 100% правильное решение, к тому же кроссбраузерное, <br><b>Palmervan</b> - зачем тут JS?

Comment: JS чтобы считать точную ширину рабочей области брацзера и под нее танцевать!

Comment: В данном случае <b>overflow</b>, скорее всего задается для <b>body</b>

Comment: Всеравно не асилил зачем тут JS, в моей практике было великое множество правок подобного рода и везде удавалось обходится средствами css...

Comment: Я же написал что для факта сделать быстрый тест не могу т.к. у меня было не великое множество такого рода правок) написал опираясь на знания без закреплений практикой)

Comment: <b>Palmervan</b> - уберите про JS и будет нормальный внятный ответ :)

Comment: Готово)

Comment: Спасибо, данный код [body { overflow-x: hidden; }] действительно помог!