# Прокрутка в div

Tags: html

Снова здраствуйте.
У меня появилась такая потребность, вот есть много контента в диве фиксированной высоты и мне надо убрать там скролл,но нужно оставить прокрутку колесиком, это вообще можно сделать?

Comment: Сразу предупреждаю - готовьте бубен и разводите костер %)

Comment: ЖЖотке однако)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="width:484px;overflow:hidden;">

   <div style="height:200px;width:500px;overflow-y:scroll;">

      Тут ваш контент

   </div>

</div>
```

1. Ширина внешнего DIV'a на 16px меньше внутреннего.
   То есть мы скрываем это скролл и все. гениально правда?

Comment: только вот в Сафари это фишка не проходит.

Comment: Протестил...<br>
не работает(чему я не удивлен).. Так что - нет, не гениально :D<br>
Впринцыпе приемлимый вариант если: вам плевать на сафари и устраивает что прокрутка происходит только при наведении на елемент с невидимым скролом

Comment: @AlexWindHope с чего ты взял что это не работает? ты в чем проверял?

Comment: В сафари(в нем всегда такие вот "ритуалы" и проверяю сразу :))<br>В остальном все вроде ок... Даже в IE работает :D<br>Единственное что не уверен так это как в стареньких операх работает...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Незачто, оброщайтесь)

Answer (score 1):

вам попутно в этут тему [Верстка дизайна сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35797/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0) только вместо body нужный div и вместо x поставит y

Comment: нееее, тогда прокручиватся не будет, не даром я написал про готовность к шаманским ритуалам :D<br>
Если не ответят и будет время завтра ченить придумаю для решения этого вопроса.<br><small>Можно кстати и чисто CSS'ом реализовать, но это будут именно шиманские ритуалы :)</small>